# Isnt this how to declare a local variable in Stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER PROC [Admin].[sp_Ques]    
(
    @QuesID bigint
 )
DECLARE @Lang int
AS
BEGIN
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you must declare it after the `BEGIN`.

Comment: fixed it..geting new error now..plz help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352551/need-help-with-some-stored-procedure-error

Comment: Serenity, did this answer your question? As an aside, I had no idea that `PROC` could be substituted for `PROCEDURE`. Neat!